# ASP and MVC returning ASCII looking characters

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ascii

Hard to describe, but this is what is being served by IIS with an ASP.NET 4.0 MVC 2.0 setup.  Does anybody have any idea as to why this is happening? It is happening locally for me as well as our staging environment on another server (making me think it's code based...).  Let me know what other information would be helpful.

Cheers

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Testing a bad ViewData element was causing the freak out.  Still strange that it decided to do that instead of return an error message though...